# What were the conditions in 17th century London prisons?

Tags: 17th-century, crime, london, law-enforcement

Does anyone have any information, or suggestions for sources, on conditions in Newgate or other London prisons in the mid-seventeenth century?

Would prisoners be confined to cells, or could they mingle? I've read 18th century accounts of women prisoners becoming pregnant in order to escape hanging, which implies some freedom of association. I know that there was a 'master's side' where prisoners with access to money could enjoy better conditions.

I've read various histories of London and searched online for info. on Newgate, but found nothing specific.

Comment: If you're willing to spend a few quid, [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=newgate+prison) has a few recently-published books about Newgate.

Comment: `women prisoners becoming pregnant in order to escape hanging` - they were impregnated by the prison wards, not other inmates.

Comment: This article is short and 19th focused but highly relevant and has references: https://perceptionsofpregnancy.com/2017/03/13/pregnancy-in-prison-past-and-present/

Comment: @BrianZ - Thank you, but pregnancy isn't what I'm interested in - I only used that example to speculate about whether prisoners had freedom to move around within the jail.

Comment: At the end of the period, Daniel Defoe wrote a lot from London jails, but I don't know how much he wrote *about* jails... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Defoe

Comment: Idk what kind of institutional access you have "The Prison Experience: disciplinary institutions and their inmates in Early Modern Europe" (2007) would probably answer your question! Afaik the answer you're looking for is - it depends. Sources from Bridewell suggest prisons were porous, in the sense that if you were well esteemed you could leave and return with relative freedom. I'm not a civil war historian but I would imagine that in the mid 17th century, like most of the state, prisons could've been rather disorganised and chaotic.